# does fread use prefetch? if so, how does it deal with consistency issue?

Tags: caching, fread, consistency, prefetch

I have a question about fread's behavior. fread is from stdio.h

I have done an experiment that if I fread(2KB), then the strace log shows there is a read()=4KB. So, this implies that fread has used "prefetch", or at least round-up to 4KB. However, if fread used prefetch and cache the data at library level, then before the program uses the "prefetched" data, it could be modified by other programs, and fread may not be aware of this modification, this will lead to an inconsistency issue.

So, what exactly does fread do? does fread have round-up, prefetch, and does fread cache at library level? how does it deal with inconsistency issue if it has used prefetch?

thanks.